# Changing the default SQL Server schema used from [dbo] to something else

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am using EF5 with the DefaultMembershipProvider and want to control the schema used in SQL Server for the tables created by the DefaultMembershipProvider.

EF5 says this is doable as:

```
modelBuidler.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("MyTable", "MySchema");
```

but as these are not "my" entities I cannot do it this way.

Questions:

1) So how do I do this in EF5?
2) Is this dealt with in EF6 when using DbModelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding more user information to ASP.NET Default Membership Provider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800975/adding-more-user-information-to-asp-net-default-membership-provider)

Comment: That post talks about changing the contents of the tables. All I want to do is change the schema the tables are placed in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed I would upgrade to EF6 and then make your context look like this, e.g.:

```
public partial class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public BlogContext()
        : base("BlogDb")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<BlogContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("");
    }
}
```

You see setting the default schema at the end to "", which also works, in my case, Oracle 12c takes the login user name as schema and everything works fine. Of course you could also load the schema name from configuration and insert it there.

Note: Automatic migrations will NOT work anymore, as this seems to confuse the system quite much. See here for a possible solution so that at least explicit migrations will work somehow: [Entity Framework using IdentityDbContext with Code First Automatic Migrations table location and schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27361700/entity-framework-using-identitydbcontext-with-code-first-automatic-migrations-ta)

Comment: Meanwhile we found out that you need to set the schema name, sad but true. Unexpected behaviour occured with empty schema name. I consider this as a bug and would file it with Oracle, but we do not have a maintenance contract.
So we wrote a method to extract the schema name from the connection string, and inject it in the context and also to set it correctly into the MigrationContext...